# What are these arguments to Rust's std::fmt::write?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make sure I understand all the examples on http://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz.html, and the one thing I am stuck on has nothing to do with FizzBuzz, but instead the arguments to write().

Consider the code below: in a line like `Fizz => f.write(b"Fizz")`, what is 'b' and where did it come from?

```
use std::fmt;

enum FizzBuzzItem {
    Fizz,
    Buzz,
    FizzBuzz,
    Number(int),
}

impl fmt::Show for FizzBuzzItem {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            Fizz => f.write(b"Fizz"),
            Buzz => f.write(b"Buzz"),
            FizzBuzz => f.write(b"FizzBuzz"),
            Number(num) => write!(f, "{}", num),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b"…"` is a byte string literal. As `"…"` has the type `&'static str`, it has the type `&'static [u8]`.

Comment: thanks. that's half of my question.  Maybe a better way to ask "where did this come from" is to ask "Where is this documented?" http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html is the closest I've found.

Comment: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html also documents it more generally, with some examples.